# Is it possible to use the Outlook 'Language' setting programmatically?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I am currently working on an C# Outlook-Add-In for my company which allows the user to plan a video conference in cisco jabber via outlook and i was wondering if it is possibly to somehow programmatically access/use the Outlook-Options "Language" setting in my code?

This is needed in order for the add-in installation to automatically set the language in the App.config based on the users existing outlook settings.

I found this question but i am for sure not allowed (i don't even know if it is possible) to access other users registries: [Outlook Version language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310259/outlook-version-language)

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Ok then, i added the tag because the add-in is written in vsto. My bad.

Comment: I think then that you wanted the vsto tag. (Visual Studio Code is a cross-platform code editor application)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accordingly to MSDN documentation, you don't need to read registry, you can use [LanguageSettings.LanguageID property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.languagesettings.languageid) to get language id.

> Specifies a language setting in a Microsoft Office application. The
> `MsoAppLanguageID` enumeration is used with the LanguageSettings member
> of the Application object to determine the language used for the
> install language, the user interface language, or the Help language.
>
> **MsoAppLanguageID enumeration (Office) Name  Value   Description**
>
> `msoLanguageIDExeMode`        4   Execution mode language.
>
> `msoLanguageIDHelp`           3   Help language.
>
> `msoLanguageIDInstall`        1   Install language.
>
> `msoLanguageIDUI`             2   User interface language.
>
> `msoLanguageIDUIPrevious`     5   User interface language used prior to the current user interface language.

In my case it's 1045, which refers to Polish language.

For further details, please see: [MsoLanguageID enumeration (Office)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.msolanguageid)

Comment: This sounds like exactly what i need, i will try it and come back to accept if it worked. Could take a day or two since i started another issue. thank you!

Comment: Yep, it returns the language IDs. No i just gotta figure out how to use them correctly. Thank you.